# Validate only numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

In one of my rails models I have this `:only_integer` validation:

```
validates :number, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

This validation also allows inputs like `+82938434` with `+`-signs.

**Which validation should I use to only allow inputs without `+` `-` only numbers?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) for `only_integer` mentions this regex :

```
/\A[+-]?\d+\z/
```

It means you could just use:

```
validates :number, format: { with: /\A\d+\z/, message: "Integer only. No sign allowed." }
```

Answer (score 5):

Rails 7 [added](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43914) `:only_numeric` option to `numericality` validator

```rb
validates :age, numericality: { only_numeric: true }
```

```rb
User.create(age: "30") # failure
User.create(age: 30) # success
```